# sql find unique values but only show todays date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to write some SQL for pulling *new* IP addresses. Here's what I have so far, but its printing everything, so I don't think its taking into account the date part.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dest_ip FROM ips WHERE date >= 2017-11-23;
```

What I want is to look at all of a given days unique IP addresses from the dest_ip field, then check if they already exist at all in the dest_ip field, if not, return them.

Here is the current database:

```
+----+------------+----------+------------------+------------------+------+
| id | date       | time     | source_ip        | dest_ip          | port |
+----+------------+----------+------------------+------------------+------+
|  1 | 2017-11-11 | 00:21:21 | 192.168.1.1      | 177.43.234.23    | 443  |
|  2 | 2017-11-11 | 14:21:07 | 192.168.1.1      | 177.43.234.45    | 443  |
|  3 | 2017-11-13 | 14:21:09 | 192.168.1.1      | 177.43.234.78    | 443  |
|  4 | 2017-11-23 | 14:21:09 | 192.168.1.1      | 177.43.234.78    | 80   |
|  5 | 2017-11-23 | 14:22:13 | 192.168.1.1      | 177.43.234.78    | 53   |
|  6 | 2017-11-23 | 13:37:13 | 192.168.1.1      | 8.8.8.8          | 53   |
+----+------------+----------+------------------+------------------+------+
```

I'd expect only ID 6 to be returned when the query was ran as this was the only new IP address for the day.

Comment: I'm using mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like that;

```
SELECT dest_ip FROM ips WHERE 
date >= 2017-11-23 and dest_ip NOT IN (SELECT dest_ip FROM ips WHERE 
date < 2017-11-23 group by dest_ip)
group by dest_ip
```

Comment: this seems to make sense logically but it displays all unique IPs (4) instead of just ID 6.

Comment: this worked in the end - select dest_ip FROM ips WHERE date >= 20171123 and dest_ip NOT IN (SELECT dest_ip FROM ips WHERE date < 20171123 group by dest_ip). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide an example of you desired output but based on what you've said and the SQL query you've written, you should be getting two IP addresses returned.

The reason for this is because in your **WHERE** clause you have said to look for all dates which are equal to or greater than 23rd Nov 2017. You would have to include the **date** column in the where clause to just get row 6.

```
create table #tbl1 (
    id int
    ,[date] date
    ,[time] time
    ,source_ip nvarchar(20)
    ,dest_ip nvarchar(20)
    ,[port] int
);

insert into #tbl1
values
    (1,'2017-11-11','00:21:21','192.168.1.1','177.43.234.23',443)
    ,(2,'2017-11-11','14:21:07','192.168.1.1','177.43.234.45', 443)
    ,(3,'2017-11-13','14:21:09','192.168.1.1','177.43.234.78',443)
    ,(4,'2017-11-23','14:21:09','192.168.1.1','177.43.234.78',80)
    ,(5,'2017-11-23','14:22:13','192.168.1.1','177.43.234.78',53)
    ,(6,'2017-11-23','13:37:13','192.168.1.1','8.8.8.8',53)
;


select
    distinct(dest_ip) as ip
from #tbl1
where
    [date] >= '20171123'
    and [time] < '14:00'
;

drop table #tbl1;
```